Weird scroll behavior when change padding on element sticky
I have simply code to explain this, i change manualy in DevTools padding bottom check and uncheck.

when scroll is on red element and I turn off padding bottom, blue element change his padding without scroll to top container



when scroll is on blue element and I turn off padding bottom manual, blue element change padding  but after a while scroll goes up untill animation stop



when i scroll to bottom page, and turn off padding scroll is not running and element correctly changes size


I need use position sticky instead of fixed,  and need behavior number 2 in second case


body {
  height: 2000px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.wrap1 {
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}

.wrap2 {
  height: 100px;
  background: blue;
  padding-bottom: 100px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  transition: padding-bottom 2s linear;
}

/* .wrap2:hover {
  padding: 0;
} */

.wrap2a {
  height: 300px;
  position: sticky;
  top: 200px;
  background: green;
}

.wrap3 {
  height: 100%;
  background: yellow;
}
<body>

  <div class="wrap1"></div>
  <div class="wrap2"></div>
  <!--   <div class="wrap2a"></div> -->
  <div class="wrap3"></div>

</body>



Codepen
I don't have idea how to fix this

It's not really clear what you're after so any improvements to the question or additional information would be good. All I can assume is that when you're at the bottom it seems to reposition the sticky element partially out of the viewport and this is probably because the space reserved for the sticky element is only accounting for some of the CSS. This means that when it's resized, it is actually changing the scroll but because the element is already out of the viewport, it's just adjusting to the reserved space.
